# WSO2 agent app not getting installed on Ipad

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

While installing the certificate of the WSO2 agent I am getting the following error `"Cannot Install Profile-Safari could not install a profile due to an unknown error"`.
The logs which I am getting are

```
<ip>- - [20/Jun/2016:16:47:54 +0530] "GET /ios-enrollment/ca HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
<ip>- - [20/Jun/2016:16:47:54 +0530] "GET /carbon/admin/login.jsp HTTP/1.1" 200 15541 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
172.17.242.31 - - [20/Jun/2016:16:47:54 +0530] "GET /emm-web-agent/enrollment/ios/download-certificate HTTP/1.1" 200 15541 "https://<ip>:9443/emm-web-agent/enrollments/ios/download-agent" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/11A501 Safari/9537.53"
```

Comment: What is the EMM version that you used?

Comment: EMM(2.0.1) ,and also triesd in the alpha version

Comment: Have to obtain an  CSR for the IP address you are running the emm server currently ? Is the device and server is connect to the same network?